# Kind of a Rendez-Vous in Java which does not work

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait, notify

I have some troubles using `wait()` and `notify()`. I need to have a kind of *rendez-vous*.

Here is the thing, in a small piece of code:

```
class A {
    private Rdv r;

    public A(Rdv r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        synchronized(r) {
            r.wait();
        }

        // ***** some stuff never reached*****
    }
}

class Rdv { 
    private int added;
    private int limit;

    public Rdv(int limit) {
        this.added = 0;
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void add() {
        this.added++;

        if(this.added == this.limit) {
            synchronized(this) {
                this.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rdv rdv = new Rdv(4);

        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                A a = new A(rdv);
                a.someMethod();
            }
        }.run();

        rdv.add();
        rdv.add();
        rdv.add();
        rdv.add();
    }
}
```

The idea is to wait until 4 threads tell "hey, i'm done" before to run the end of `someMethod()`.
But the `wait()` lasts forever, despite of the `notifyAll()`.

I don't get how

Comment: There are many many errors in your code. The most important one is that you have only one thread: the main thread. Read the Java tutorial about concurrency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ Once you have understood everything in this tutorial, consider using Thread.join().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wait()` and `notify()` are not meant to be used directly but rather are primitives that better libraries use for low-level synchronization.

You should use a higher-level concurrency mechanism, such as [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).  You would want to use a `CountDownLatch` with a value of 4.  Have each of the threads call the `countDown()` method of the latch, and the one you want to wait to call `await()`.

```
private CountDownLatch rendezvousPoint = new CountDownLatch(4);

//wait for threads
rendezvousPoint.await();

//do stuff after rendezvous

//in the other 4 threads:
rendezvousPoint.countDown();
```

Comment: Well, with RMI it does not work, since it is not Serializable, so I had to find another way. But yeah, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 3):

Um... am I the only one noticing that you are not actually starting any threads?

```
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            A a = new A(rdv);
            a.someMethod();
        }
    }.run();
```

should be

```
 Thread t = new Thread(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            A a = new A(rdv);
            a.someMethod();
        }
    });
 t.start();
```

And this should be executed 4 times if you want to have 4 threads waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of messing with `wait()` and `notify()` yourself, consider using a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it won't be reached, because every instance of class A has a different instance of class Rdv;

You need to use RDV as a static variable in class A